# AWS heartbeat service using API Gateway / Lambda / DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, throughput, capacity

I'm using a local windows application and I want to be able to know when this application is offline (not later than one minute delay).

I was thinking to create an api gateway called HeartbeatControllerAPI and this api will call a lambda which in turns will set the last heartbeat of the app inside dynamodb table called "Heartbeats" looks like that:

Machine Name | Last Heartbeat

A                  2:00 AM

B                  2:10 AM

C                  2:05 AM

Therefore if I have 3 machines as following:

Machine 1 - with the app installed.

Machine 2 - with the app installed.

Machine 3 - with the app installed.

Then I though that each minute all the machine will do the work as I described above and then I will be able to know which machine is offline / online.

Is this method is right? I'm worried (from billing and overload perspective) what happened if I had 1 millions machines like these whereas on each minute all of them will access the api gateway and update the dynamodb table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a heartbeat is the other way around, where in your case you would do something like have the Lambda triggered by a CloudWatch event (cron event, triggered every X minutes), and that Lambda would call your machines and confirm that they are up and running. This way, your machines are left to do their task, and your heartbeat function (the Lambda) will confirm they are working every X minutes.

This would also mean you only need a single Lambda for a lot of machines (depending on performance, can increase the amount of Lambdas if you reach something like 50 machines maybe).

So if you follow this approach, your Lambda will get triggered by CloudWatch cron event, check if the machines are running and then for each machine if they are running will update the table with the status, and if they aren't, you could maybe send a message to an SNS topic (and subscribe yourself to that topic) so that you can be notified of a machine being down (this is also something that is a lot more complicated if the machine is the one calling, because if it's down then you have to scan the table for the last updated time, it can get costly and inefficient).

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand you besides one detail. How can I know from within the Lambda function running via cron if a machine is up and running and is connected to the internet. Do you mean I should save the public IP of these computers and try ping from the server to see if they are up?

Comment: Yes, either save their public IP (maybe using SSM Parameter Store), or open a port for them to be accessible through for a status

Comment: Deiv, this way , trying to access to local computer from the server using the IP, I might have problems with the router. Isn't it too much complicated this way? I can overcome the firewall but the router might do some troubles.

Comment: Hmm in this case your approach might be the only way...let me think. Okay so what I would do in this scenario is make an API gateway proxy to dynamodb, map the request so that a call to it updates the table with a timestamp. This way, you can have hundreds of machines calling this API and you don't invoke any extra Lambdas. Then, you can have a timer based Lambda that scans the table and searches for machines that weren't updated in the past X minutes and then you know something is wrong so you send an alert

Comment: I was thinking about this but this is good for hundreds I'm not sure how good it is for millions. I found an article to implement lambdas as Websocket instead of simple REST. This might solve the issue. Each machine can send connect request to the lambda, the connect id is saved in dynamo db and then I can send back messages to the clients with these connect ids. What do you think about this?

Comment: I think if you're talking in the millions you definitely want to avoid having a Lambda as a middle man, because you'll be getting millions of unnecessary invocations. Having a lambda is good for hundreds, but a proxy directly to dybamodb is good for any number as there's no lambda in between :)

Comment: Great so I will go with the lambda as websocket and see how it fits . Thank you